# Pipes angular 2 filter multiple columns considering null value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe, lodash

I am using pipe to filter data on three different columns in a data table.
The names of the column are `category`, `name`,`department`.

I am passing the arguments as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped"  [mfData]="listdata | dataFilter : filtername : filterDep : filterCategory">
```

I have `*ngFor` loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i =index">
    <td>
        {{i+1}}
    </td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{item.department}}</td>
    <td>{{item.category}}</td>

</tr>
```

The code which sets the query variable is

```
<th colspan="2">
    Filter by name:
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filtername" (input)="change()" />
</th>
<th colspan="1">
    Filter by Department:
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterDep" (input)="change()" />
</th>
<th colspan="1">
    Filter by Category:
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterCategory" (input)="change()" />
</th>
```

I have data in which some of the `category` is `null`.

The pipe which I am using is:

```
@Pipe({
   name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string, query2: string, query3: string): any {

        let notNullCategory = _.reject(array, ['category', null]);

        if (query || query2 || query3) {

            return _.filter(notNullCategory, row => ((row.name.indexOf(query) > -1) && (row.department.indexOf(query2) > -1) && (row.category.indexOf(query3) > -1)));

        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

This way if the user makes the search with some `name` only the rows which have non null values of `category` are considered.

I want to take in consideration the rows with null values as well , but I am unable to do so.

If I change my pipe to:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string, query2: string, query3: string): any {
        if (query || query2 || query3) {

            return _.filter(array, row => ((row.name.indexOf(query) > -1) && (row.department.indexOf(query2) > -1) && (row.category.indexOf(query3) > -1)));

        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the query variable is not being set

Comment: Where is your code that sets thisvariable

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen I have three text boxes which sets the query variable. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if each `row`'s name, department or catigory is null:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string,query2: string,query3: string): any {

        if(query || query2 || query3)
        {

            return  _.filter(array, row => 
            {
                var hasName =       row.name && row.name.indexOf(query) > -1;
                var hasDepartment = row.department && row.department.indexOf(query2) > -1
                var hasCategory =   row.category && row.category.indexOf(query3) > -1
                return hasName && hasDepartment && hasCategory;
            });
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this, but it still doesn't gives the search result which also includes results which have the null value as category. (when the user only searches for name).

Comment: I think im lost on what you are asking, can you post a sample array and sample queries with their respective expected output you are looking for? This will help me understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter category only when category is not null you can do this:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: any[], name: string, department: string, category: string): any {

        if (name || department || category) {
            _.filter(array, row => ((row.name.indexOf(name) > -1)
                && (row.department.indexOf(department) > -1)
                && (row.category ? row.category.indexOf(category) > -1 : true))
            );
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working fine for me when i search for multiple columns.

```
 transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
  if(searchText == null) return categories;

  return categories.filter(function(category){
    var name_search=category.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > 
      -1;
    var email_search=category.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) 
     > -1;
    return name_search || email_search;
  })

}
```

Previously i was having issues when i use this "import * as _ from "lodash";
" that is,the data was not displaying when i load the page but when i search the data, filter was working fine and data also displaying..